# Is it possible to make agreements fields not required?

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-agreements

is it possible to make agreements fields on checkout billing screen not required?
They are added from Stores -> Terms and Conditions in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make checkout agreements field not required then its simplest solutions is **`disable the terms and condtions status`**.
If you can disable terms and condtions then its not display inside checkout billing.

if you want keep some terms and conditions, its mandotory required to choose at checkout step.Generally its useful when you have to some Terms and condtions for your site.

Answer (score 0):

@Mateusz_Procner, did you find the solution to the issue raised?

I need some agreements to be obligatory(required) and others not, but all to be displayed to the user.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194323)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir thank you for advice